# How to compile zsh on/for an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, zsh, cydia, theos

**Background**

I recently changed from bash to zsh as my default shell and have quickly gotten used to the awesomeness that's added by associated tools ([prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), [zaw](https://github.com/zsh-users/zaw) and [zsh-dwim](https://github.com/oknowton/zsh-dwim)).

I wanted to have a similar setup on iPhone as well. However, only zsh v.4.3.10 is available from the default repos and that's not supported by prezto:

[image]

Would you know how I should go about compiling zsh from source for the iPhone? I attempted to use [Theos](http://sharedinstance.net/2013/12/build-on-windows/) to build something on my Win7 box, but am greeted with the following errors after doing the `make package install`:

```
/home/blah/projects/ashrocks/theos/makefiles/targets/Cygwin/iphone.mk:38: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Bootstrapping CydiaSubstrate...
Compiling iPhoneOS CydiaSubstrate stub... default target? failed, what?
cp: cannot stat `_out/*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `libsubstrate.dylib': No such file or directory
Generating substrate.h header...
Making all for tweak ashrocks...
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm...
/bin/sh: theos/toolchain/windows/iphone/bin/armv7-apple-darwin11-clang++: No such file or directory
/home/blah/projects/ashrocks/theos/makefiles/instance/rules.mk:144: recipe for target 'obj/Tweak.xm.666c9a3c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.666c9a3c.o] Error 127
/home/blah/projects/ashrocks/theos/makefiles/instance/library.mk:19: recipe for target 'internal-library-all_' failed
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
/home/blah/projects/ashrocks/theos/makefiles/master/rules.mk:54: recipe for target 'ashrocks.all.tweak.variables' failed
make: *** [ashrocks.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Would you know how the command line tools availabe in Cydia were compiled ?

Comment: Am currently following this link : https://sites.google.com/site/theostutorials/use-your-computer-to-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you don't have the standard libraries compiled for the iPhone on your computer. Try setting up `gcc` on your iPhone by following [these instructions](http://iklive.org/cc-compiling-on-ios/). I have done this and have successfully compile various pieces of software.